# How do I limit the amount of letters in a string

Tags: python, string, variables, limit

I have a program that asks a the user to input a question, the program then answers it.
What I want to know is how do I limit the amount of letters a user can input into a variable.

Comment: slice the string if you want to limit it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python's `input` function cannot do this directly; but you can truncate the returned string, or repeat until the result is short enough.

```
# method 1
answer = input("What's up, doc? ")[:10]  # no more than 10 characters

# method 2
while True:
    answer = input("What's up, doc? ")
    if len(answer) <= 10:
        break
    else:
        print("Too much info - keep it shorter!")
```

If that's not what you're asking, you need to make your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me insight how to do it :)

Answer (score 6):

You can get only the first n characters of the input text like so:

```
data = raw_input()[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with builtin `len` function:

```
my_input = raw_input("Enter something ")
if len(my_input) > 3:
  print "More then 3"
else:
  print "Ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
while True:
    answer = input("What's up, doc? ")
    if len(answer) >= 10:
        print("Too much info - keep it shorter!")
```